# How to pick Data from JSON Value

Tags: javascript, json

This is My JSON Data

```
var data = [{
    meal_com_id: "1",
    company_name: "PeryCap",
    pic: "https://shopgo.in/upload/1545849409-1518284057-Untitled-nn1.png",
    status: "1",
    details: "sdvaebfvhjaebfber itnwiuore tg5ykrgt wiretgi34 tgi3rgtiquogtiq",
    Address:
    "B.L. Behind Dhaldighi Petrol Pump, Burdwan, B.L.Hati Rd, Khosbagan Burdwan West Bengal 713101",
    day_meal: "42",
    night_meal: "25"
}];
```

how to pick particular data from it using javascript

```
var day_meal= data.day_meal;
```

Comment: Its an array. Try using data[0].day_meal

Comment: var test =data[0].day_meal;
alert(test); undefined

Comment: You JSON is not properly escaping the quotes, and thus, is invalid JSON.

Comment: You should use single quotes for the surrounding quotes, if not your compiler will scream at you..

Comment: i am check the json data with json formattor and validator   [  
   {  
      "meal_com_id":"1",
      "company_name":"PeryCap",
      "pic":"https:\/\/shopgo.in\/upload\/1545849409-1518284057-Untitled-nn1.png",
      "status":"1",
      "details":"sdvaebfvhjaebfber itnwiuore tg5ykrgt wiretgi34 tgi3rgtiquogtiq",
      "Address":"B.L. Behind Dhaldighi Petrol Pump, Burdwan, B.L.Hati Rd, Khosbagan Burdwan West Bengal 713101",
      "day_meal":"42",
      "night_meal":"25"
   }
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given data is stringified form of the JSON so you first need to parse that to get the actual array and since this array has one object you can access that object with index 0 and after that access the `day_meal` property of that object:

```js
var data = '[{"meal_com_id":"1","company_name":"PeryCap","pic":"https://shopgo.in/upload/1545849409-1518284057-Untitled-nn1.png","status":"1","details":"sdvaebfvhjaebfber itnwiuore tg5ykrgt wiretgi34 tgi3rgtiquogtiq","Address":"B.L. Behind Dhaldighi Petrol Pump, Burdwan, B.L.Hati Rd, Khosbagan Burdwan West Bengal 713101","day_meal":"42","night_meal":"25"}]';
var dayMeal = JSON.parse(data)[0].day_meal;
console.log(dayMeal);
```